# Using jQuery to change onclick attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC 5, I have a controller `Image`, with an action `Info`, which takes a string parameter `id`. In a view, I have a button `info`, and I want to change its `onclick` attribute using jQuery. Within the jQuery, there is a string variable called `file`, which I want to pass as the parameter.

I have tried the following two solutions, but neither work.

**Solution 1:**

```
$("#info").attr('onclick', "location.href='@Url.Action("Info", "Image")?id='" + file);
```

This sets the `onclick` attribute to be equal to:

```
location.href='/Image/Info?id='1234
```

(here, `1234` is the value of `file`).

**Solution 2:**

```
$("#info").attr('onclick', "location.href='@Url.Action("Info", "Image")?id=' + file + ");
```

This sets the `onclick` attribute to be equal to:

```
location.href='/Image/Info?id=' + file +
```

Neither of these work when the button is pressed. What's the solution?

Comment: Try to use $("#info").on('click', function(){});

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you do this sort of thing in JavaScript. Once you're client-side, you just bind directly to the event:

```
$('#info').on('click', function () {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So what do I now put in place of the `// do something` in order to call the `Info` action and passing `file` as a parameter?

Comment: Umm... the same thing? The point is that adding an `onclick` attribute, after the fact, isn't going to work. You have to bind to the event. What you do on click is the same. This is pretty basic stuff. Perhaps you should give the docs a good read: http://api.jquery.com/on/